# Nothing happen with bower install

Tags: node.js, angularjs, yeoman, bower

I'm trying to setup angular app with yeoman, following this steps: http://yeoman.io/
Everything works fine until I do

```
grunt test
```

I got

```
Chrome 24.0.1312 (Linux) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at /var/www/moviz-test/app/scripts/app.js:3
Chrome 24.0.1312 (Linux) ERROR
    Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at /var/www/moviz-test/app/scripts/controllers/main.js:3
```

It's because `bower install` do nothing, I don't have the folder `app/bower_components`

**.bowerrc**

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

**bower.json**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.0.7",
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~2.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.8",
    "angular-resource": "~1.0.7",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.0.7",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.0.7",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.0.7"
  }
}
```

I've uninstall and reinstall bower and nothing change

```
bower -v 1.2.3

node -v v0.10.17
```

Comment: Does `bower` give any output?

Comment: Nothing, but I rebooted and it's ok now; strange

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. The reason was that I was following old tutorial that said bower's package file was components.json instead of bower.json. So bower was looking for later and as it couldn't find file it would just say nothing (it should actually show warning or error). When I renamed file to bower.json it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't install newest ember package because `bower install` did nothing, but:

1. `cd bower_components`
2. `rm -rf package-name`
3. now `bower install`

helped.